# How to go from Ataturk domestic terminal on arrival level to Ataturk international terminal on departure level?

Tags: transit, short-connections, istanbul, turkish-airlines

In March I will be flying from Turkey to Italy. The first flight is from Izmir to Istanbul Ataturk, and lands at 16:10. The second flight is from Istanbul Ataturk to Venice (Italy) and takes off at 17:25 on the same day, so I have 1 hour 15 minutes between arrival and departure.

The connection is shown on Turkish Airlines website, but I did not buy the two tickets together because it was much more expensive than buying the separate tickets.

I am afraid there will be not enough time to transfer from the arrival level (domestic flights) to the departure level (international flights). How do I move from the arrival level to the departure level? Are there security controls between the two levels? How much time before take-off does the international boarding close?

Comment: Will you have checked luggage? This seems like it would be entirely impossible if so; [Turkish Airlines closes check-in desks](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-at/any-questions/check-in/) an hour before international flights.

Comment: Knowing the airport pretty well, I will say that the chance of success of you making your connecting flight to Venice are really low. The only possibility of actually making the connection are if you are flying business class or have Star Alliance status that allows you to get priority baggage handling/check in/security at the airport.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments, putting on hold.